# Given the angle find the dot product

Tags: calculus

[image]

I understand how to get $v \cdot w$ but not quite sure how to go about solving for (b) and (c)

Any suggestions or tips would be very grateful.

Comment: A very "hands on" approach is to write $w = \cos(.5)\,v + \sin(.5)\,u$, where $u$ is orthogonal to $v$ and has length $4$.

Comment: Use the fact that $\|3v-w\|=\sqrt{(3v-w)\cdot(3v-w)}$ and algebraic properties of the dot product.

Answer (score 0):

The norm of a vector is the square root of its dot product with itself. Now use the linearity of the dot product to express it in terms of $\|v\|$, $\|w\|$, and $v\cdot w$.